# How to set value of a ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, django, models

while learning Django to do web programming,I faced this problem.
I searched Google and Django's official website biut could not find any answer. Please help me.

System environment:

1. Fedora 18
2. Python 2.7
3. Django 1.5.1
4. Eclipse + PyDev

Runtime: Django's development server

I have a models includes ManyToMany field.When I set value by django's admin panel,everything goes well.
Codes below are all of my models:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    post_authorid = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Authorid')
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name=u'PostDate')
    post_date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name=u'LastModifiedTime')
    post_content = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Content')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name=u'Title')
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,verbose_name=u'ShortName') 
    post_cover = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=u'CoverUrl')      
    post_introduction = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,verbose_name=u'introduction')
    post_status = models.ForeignKey(Status,verbose_name=u'status')
    comment_status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'show_comments')
    post_password = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,verbose_name=u'passwd')
    post_tagid = models.ManyToManyField(Tags,verbose_name=u'tag')
    post_threadtypeid = models.ForeignKey(ThreadTypes,verbose_name=u'ThreadType')
    post_comment_conut = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'CommentsCount')
    post_comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comments,blank=True,verbose_name=u'Comment')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s %s" % (self.id,self.post_title,self.post_date)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['post_date']
class Tags(models.Model):
    tagname = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name=u'标签名称')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.id,self.tagname)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

In my python shell,i input:

```
post = Posts（）

post.post_tagid = Tags.objects.get(id='1')
```

then django rasise a http 500 error:

> object needs to have a value for field "posts" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

But,when i use :

```
post= Posts.objects.get(id='1')
```

Note- I have input the Posts object by Django admin

Then,when i use

```
post.post_tagid = Tags.objects.get(id='1')
```

everything goes well.

**Q:How can i add a ManyToMany field without this error raising?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It looks like the problem here is that you're trying to add something to the M2M table before it's actually created in the database.

When you run `post = Posts（）` you create an object in memory, but **not** in the database. So when you then try to add a new entry to the M2M table there is nothing to reference. (Remember that declaring an M2M field causes the creation of a new table with records that point to both ends of the relationship.)

The solution is to run `post.save()` before trying to add to the M2M table. (The Django admin is doing this for you behind the scenes.)

So try something like this:

```
post = Posts（）

# now set up the post (title, name, etc.)

post.save() # adds a new entry to the Posts table

post.post_tagid.add(tag) # now that your post exists in the DB this should work
```

Comment: But `post.post_tagid.add(tag)` does not save tag for me, is there any common reason? the code I am using is `res = super().save()
        if creating:
            self.post_tagid.add(self.other_foreignkey_tag_field) 
            `  in save method of Post, even i tried `self.save` at the end but it still does not save post_tagid but other_foreignkey_tag_field shows the tag field value saved

Answer (score 5):

You should read official django docs on [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

In your case following code should help:

```
# Post object
post= Posts.objects.get(id=1)

# Two tag objects
tag1 = Tags.objects.get(id=1)
tag2 = Tags.objects.get(id=2)


# Add tag objects to Post object
post.post_tagid.add(tag1, tag2)
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but neither i use post.post_tagid.add() or use '=' operator, django raise the same error.

Comment: I followed this document and got nothing,the porblem arise too.   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager

Comment: when i use dir(post),python shows me that it has the atrribute 'post_tagid' but when i input'post.post_tagid',the same error info arises.

Comment: Is there anything else needed?